# printing a tree using bfs. quick fix needed

Tags: algorithm, tree, b-tree, breadth-first-search

So I'm printing a b-tree by level. A node has max 3 keys and max 4 children, its your typical 2-3-4 tree. The code works fine for most stuff except for when I add "2 5 8 1 3 6 9 7 11 12 10 4". Specifically the problem is push (2 5) and (11) on my queue then count (2 5) children. Afterwards I go to pop its children but (11) is in the way and screws it up.

```
void BFS(TwoThreeFourTree tree, Node start)
{
    ArrayList<String> level = new ArrayList<String>();
    int levCount = 0;

    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    queue.add(start);
    level.add("(" + keys(start) + ")");
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        Node vertix = queue.remove();
        for (Node child : vertix.child)
        {
            if (child == null) break;
            queue.add(child);
            levCount++;
        }

        String allChild = "";
        Node temp[] = new Node[levCount];
        while (levCount > 0)
        {
            temp[levCount - 1] = queue.remove();
            allChild = allChild.concat("(" + keys(temp[levCount - 1]) + ")");
            levCount--;
        }
        for (Node child : temp)
            queue.addFirst(child);
        if (levCount == 0 && allChild != "")
            level.add(allChild);
    }
    for (String stuff : level)
    {
        System.out.println(stuff);
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------");
}
```

Comment: Yay!! Reading someones undocumented code for free! Time for a drink!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that your algorithm is incorrect. When you start an iteration of the loop and your queue is non-empty, you add 'levCount' nodes at the end of the queue, but then you fetch 'levCount' nodes from the beginning (queue.remove()) and they have nothing to do with the nodes you added to the end. It's not usual / genuine BFS search but a buggy version of it. Normal BFS search follows this pseudocode:

```
while (queue is not empty)
   node = remove first from queue
   <process / print node>
   for each child of node
      push child to queue
```

If your desire is to process each **level** in a BFS fashion you need a different algorithm.